# Вылетает ОС на VirtualBox

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, ос, macbook

Установил VirtualBox на MacBook. После этого устанавливаю на VirtualBox OC Linux и на последней стадии установки, после перезагрузки ОС, ОС вылетает и начинает установка OC Linux заново. Кто-то говорит, что это связано с правами доступа на MacBook. Если кто-то знает в чем проблема, буду рад вашей помощи

Comment: а виртуальный диск с образом вытянули? скорее всего нет

Comment: Извлеките виртуальный CD-ROM из VirtualBox. Если вы установили VirtualBox, все нужные права уже есть.

Comment: Да, диск с образом вытянули